# How to create / beautify month names in Excel?

Tags: excel, plot, excel-formula, time-series

I have a time-series data collected as this :

```
Year    Month   Data

2015    1       0,92
2015    2       0,91
2015    3       0,90
```

and I want to plot it to have month strings like `February 2015` in the x-axis.

Can I do this with an extra column with a formula before `Data`, or how can I do this?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-29cea14b-bd86-426c-9985-cb2f0b19df58 is good to keep as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following as a formula (assuming year is in cell A1 and month is in cell B1)

```
=TEXT(DATE(A4,B4,1),"mmmm-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I needed to change the separators to semi-colons, (and the function names to my local language), I made it work but the output is : `mmmm-2015`. Any idea why? **Edit:** , oh I need to change the m's and y's too.. And now it is giving the output in my language, whereas I want it in English, but that's another problem ! Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Considering the language issue:

```
=CHOOSE(B3;"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December")&" "&A3
```

However, these are strings and an axis based on them will not be a time scale.